# Asignación de valores enteros en C a partir de un menú de opción múltiple usando la estructura do-while-switch

Tags: c, bucles, while

Buen día a todos.
Estoy intentando hacer un pequeño programa que, con base en diversos factores, señale el riesgo de los usuarios en caso de contagiarse una enfermedad. Los factores estarán predefinidos por mi y el usuario únicamente deberá señalar el aplicable a este; por ejemplo, su sexo.

Cada opción asigna un puntaje diferente que se va acumulando en un contador (en este caso, la variable "puntos"). Finalmente, de acuerdo con el valor final de "puntos" se imprime en pantalla el nivel de riesgo estimado.

Mi idea, a efecto de evitar que ingresen factores no contemplados, es otorgarles un menú de opciones para que unicamente señalen la que les sea aplicable, para lo cual, de acuerdo con lo investigado, puedo usar la estructura do-while-switch.

No obstante lo anterior, estoy teniendo problemas con el programa, pues no realiza ninguna acción, solo imprime en diversas ocasiones el mismo menú de opciones:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char sexo;
    int puntos;

printf("Selecciona el número que corresponda a tu sexo: ");

    do
    {
        printf( "\n   1. Masculino.");
        printf( "\n   2. Femenino.");
        printf( "\n   3. Salir." );

        /* Filtramos la opción elegida por el usuario */
        do
        {
            printf( "\n   Introduzca opci%cn (1-3): ");
            scanf( "%d", &sexo);

        } while ( sexo < 1 || sexo > 3 );
        /* La opción sólo puede ser 1, 2, o 3 */

        switch (sexo)
        {
            case 1: puntos = 50;
                    printf(puntos);
                    break;

            case 2: puntos = 30;
                    printf(puntos);
                    break;
         }

    } while ( sexo != 3 );

    return 0;
}
```

Espero que alguien pueda echarme una mano, pues llevo desde ayer intentando con esto y no hallo la solución.

Saludos.

**EDITO:** Solucioné el problema con la respuesta de @MrDave1999; no obstante, se me presentó una cuestión más que quisiera plantear aquí mismo a efecto de no abrir otra pregunta, toda vez que es relativo al mismo código:

De acuerdo con lo comentado, quiero que con base en los puntos acumulados se despliegue un nivel de riesgo, sin embargo por alguna razón me está desplegando los resultados para cualquier rango. Estoy usando el condicional if y else, pero de cualquier manera me continua desplegando todo:

```
 if(puntos >0 || puntos < 140){
        printf("\n El factor de riesgo en caso de contraer coronavirus es de: Nivel Medio");
    }
    if (puntos >139 || puntos <170){
        printf("\n El factor de riesgo en caso de contraer coronavirus es de: Nivel Alto");
    }
    else (puntos > 170);{
        printf("\n El factor de riesgo en caso de contraer coronavirus es de: Nivel Muy Alto\n");
    }
```

Infinitas gracias de antemano.

Comment: En vez de usar el operador `||` (operador OR), debería ser: `&&` (operador AND)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema radica en la forma como estás imprimiendo los puntos:

```c
case 1: puntos = 50;
     printf(puntos);
     break;

case 2: puntos = 30;
     printf(puntos);
    break;
```

El primer parámetro de la función [printf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) espera la dirección de memoria del primer elemento de un **array de caracteres** y tú le estás pasando un entero. Ahí el programa tiene [comportamiento indefinido](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comportamiento_indefinido).

**Solución:**

```c
case 1: puntos = 50;
     printf("%d\n", puntos);
     break;

case 2: puntos = 30;
     printf("%d\n", puntos);
    break;
```

El especificador `%d` indica lo que se va a imprimir, que en este caso es un entero.